# Dynamics AX 2009 - Rename Financial Dimensions

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2009

We are having an issue with the length of a financial dimensions going to FRx. The new dimension; "INTDESIGN" is 9 characters obviously, but FRx seems to only accept 8. There aren't many posted transactions in AX to clean up, but I am curious if there's a way to rename this dimension in AX automatically without writing my own job. I did some google searching, but could only find AX 2012 material.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rename the primary key of any entity by right-clicking on the record, selecting 'Record Info' and then clicking the 'Rename' button. Note that you may need to right-click on the actual primary key field (Number in this case).

It should prompt you for what the new key is, and when you click 'OK' it will rename the key and all places that key is used.

See also: https://ax-dynamics.com/renaming-primary-key/

Comment: I'll test it out. Thanks.